# how to debug playing videos on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, apache, quicktime, x-sendfile

I am trying to play videos through a proxy using php on iphone, the video format is .mp4 and it works on every other device and browser through both proxy and through direct access. The Iphone will work on on direct access but not through the proxy (X-SendFile Apache).

How I can debug to see what Iphone/Apple/eQuicktime is not liking, the headers all look correct.

Thanks for your help